# Electron IPC messages

Tags: angular, electron, ipc

I'm building an app using electron with angular. One functionality I want to achieve is after pressing a button, before the whole procedure start, I want to pop up a dialog message box to the user to show him a message. Depending if the user pressed yes or no, I return the result from main.js to component and I call or not call the appropriate method that exists in component.

The problem is angular gives me an error (Cannot set property of undefined) according to the scope I think.

Here is my try:

**Component A:**

```
//method of button
this.IpcService.send('navigateToMessageWindow', null);
this.IpcService.on('getDialogResault', function (event, arg) { 
   //here is the problem if i call another method it doesnt see it. and gives me an error.
});
```

**Main.js**

```
ipcMain.on('navigateToMessageWindow', (event, arg) => {
    const options = {
        type: 'question',
        buttons: ['Cancel', 'Yes', 'No'],
        defaultId: 2,
        title: 'Information',
        message: 'This procedure will take some minutes to complete. Are you sure you want to continue?',
    };

    dialog.showMessageBox(null, options).then((data) => {
        event.sender.send('getDialogResault', [data.response]);
    });
});
```

**Ipc Service:**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ElectronService } from 'ngx-electron';

@Injectable({
    providedIn: 'root'
 })

export class IpcService {

    constructor(private _electronService: ElectronService) { }

    public on(channel: string, listener: Function): void {
        this._electronService.ipcRenderer.on(channel, (evt, args) => listener(evt, args));
    }

    public send(channel: string, ...args): void {
        this._electronService.ipcRenderer.send(channel, args);
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you call the functions in your component a where the error happens?

Comment: it would be helpful if you could add more about the error - what object is exactly undefined here?

Comment: @Rhayene for example i will tell you a simple example: under class i have defined a variable like stopLoop: boolean = false; now inside this.IpcService.on('getDialogResault', function (event, arg)  if i call the variable like this.stopLoop = true i got error like this: TypeError: Cannot set property 'stopLoop' of undefined. For everywhere else in class i havent this error and functionality of dialog window its working well.

Comment: please edit your question with new informationen for better reading

Comment: since you used the function syntax for your callback function, `this` may refer to the callback function - not the class in this context. My first step in debugging this would be to use an arrow function in the event listener to exclude this possibility. It would be helpful if you could add your sample, which reproduces the error into your question (including the surrounding class and class field) by editing your question. This way the information is together in one place and will not get lost, when the comments get purged.

Comment: @Rhayene using arrow function solved the issue thanks a lot mate!

Answer (score 0):

Using arrow function like above, solved the issue.

```
this.IpcService.send('navigateToMessageWindow', null);
        this.IpcService.on('getDialogResault', (event, arg) => {
 });
```